# Find a value based on a table result

Tags: sql, postgresql

First of all, sorry for the title. Couldn't think of any better title.
 This is what I got:

```
SELECT study FROM old_employee;
  study    
---------
 STUDY1
 STUDY2
 STUDY3
 STUDY1
 STUDY2


 SELECT id,name_string FROM studies;
 id |    name_string    
----+-------------------
  1 | STUDY1
  2 | STUDY2
  3 | STUDY3
```

Now I would like to find the id's based on the first output. This is what i've attempted but obviously it's not working.

```
SELECT id FROM studies WHERE name_string LIKE (SELECT study FROM old_employee);
```

My desired output:

```
 id    
----
 1
 2
 3
 1
 2
```

edit:  I'm saving old_employee as a view and i'm wondering if there's a smarter way of including it in the answers below instead of creating this view first.

```
CREATE VIEW old_employee AS
  SELECT *
    FROM dblink('dbname=mydb', 'select study from personnel')
    AS t1(study char(10));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished without using [SQL LIKE Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp). Here is the query.

```
SELECT s.id
FROM studies s,
     old_employee o
WHERE s.name_string = o.study;
```

Second query (According to what @a_horse_with_no_name said):

```
SELECT studies.id
FROM studies
INNER JOIN old_employee 
ON studies.name_string = old_employee.study
```

Comment: Please stop using implicit joins in the `where` clause and use a proper `JOIN` operator.

Comment: I wrote a second query based on your advice. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Thank you it worked. Can you check my edit and maybe give an answer to that too?

Comment: @LottoKuma yes it did.

Comment: @Blazyb This should be the way but there may be better answer for it. Sorry, I don't know any better answer though.